# Graphics-debugging for html5 video?

Tags: javascript, html, video, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Recently I noticed a certain looping full-screen video tag breaking on *one* computer - A Win8 system that apparently has problems with older drivers for the amd/nvidia graphics.

The odd thing is, I would usually get an error (with videoelement.error) in Chrome, yet when the video element broke in Firefox I would get no videoelement.error or videoelement.pause, despite the fact that the video was broken (showing placeholder image).

Are there any dev-tools that help to debug this sort of failure that seems to be limited to specific machines/specific graphics card combinations? Or is there a debug version of Chrome/Firefox that will give enough debug information to diagnose graphics problems like this?

Answer (score 0):

As always, as a web developer you should use [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/developer/).

There are a couple of tools that may give you more information:

- You could try the web console: "Tools" -> "Web Developer" -> "Web
  Console."
- Or the browser console: "Tools" -> "Web Developer" ->
  "Browser Console."
- Or maybe launch Firefox from the commandline as a lot of information is logged there.

Comment: The first two I've used - Is there any particular commandline option to get more graphics debugging info?

Comment: You can download a debug build here as they log a heckuvalot more info:
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/tinderbox-builds/

You probably want mozilla-aurora-win32-debug.